# DateTimePicker date to string (custom format)

Tags: visual-c++

Here is format what I want to get yyMMddHHmmssWWNZ

```
array<Char>^date_ = this->date_datepicker->Value.ToString("yyMMddHHmmssWWNZ")->ToCharArray();
```

How can I get week number and week day number from selected date?
right now I get only "120810144500WWNZ"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.aspx

```
weeknr = GetWeekOfYear()

weekdaynr = GetDayOfWeek()
```